# Python: How to continue overwrite the code after "Return True"

Tags: python, replace, return, continue

**The following is the basic function:**

In the `CheckReady.txt` file, there can be `1` or `0`

After it reads `1`, it should return True, and then replace `1` to `0` to complete reset

If it reads `0`, then it will return false.

**Below is my code:**

```
def CheckReady():
    s = open("CheckReady.txt").read()
    print "Ready= ",s
    if s == "1":
        print "ready"
        return True
        s = s.replace("1", "0");
        f = open ("TrakStarReady.txt",'w')
        f.write(s)
        print "Ready= ",s, "Reset Complete"
    elif s == "0":
        print "not ready"
        return False
    f.close()
```

**Here is my question:**

I know that after `return True`, the code will stop to do replace `1` to `0`... i'm really new in programming...tried many times,but have no idea how to fix that.

Could someone help me to fix this problem and complete the basic function?

Comment: I'm not sure, what exactly you want to reach, but what about just moving the return statement down to after the print?

Comment: Your code will rise `NameError` if s="0"...

Comment: Once a return statement is executed, no other piece of code within that function will be executed. Also, you cannot refer to a variable before it has been created. Notice that your final statement is `f.close()` but `f` is only assigned to `if s == "1"`. What if s is not equal to 1 and is not equal to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do everything you want to do, and then return:

```
def CheckReady():
    with open("CheckReady.txt") as check:
        s = check.read()
    print "Ready= ",s
    if s == "1":
        print "ready"
        s = "0"
        with open("TrakStarReady.txt",'w') as trak:
            trak.write(s)
        print "Ready= ",s, "Reset Complete"
        return True
    else:
        print "not ready"
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to open the CheckReady file. Instead, use the file as a "marker". If you're not ready, have the file moved to a temp location. When it is ready, rename it.

Here's how I would improve it:

```
import os 

def CheckReady():
  if os.path.isfile('/my/path/ready.txt'):
    # the file exists. Reset the marker
    os.rename('/my/path/ready.txt', '/my/path/notready.txt')
    with open ("TrakStarReady.txt",'w'):
      f.write(1)
    return True
  else:
    print "not ready"
    return False
```